# Reflection Catcher showing in render but not appearing in saved PNG image

Tags: compositing-nodes, reflection

I have a simple scene with a cube and a plane.
I followed some tutorials that allowed me to create a basic Reflection Catcher, so that I can add my rendered footage to a video.
Everything seems to work well. This is the render output:
[image]

I achieved it by using this compositing setup:
[image]

For some reason I cannot understand, this is what happens when I save the render result as a PNG file:
[image]

Where did the reflections go?! Please help me figure it out.
Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: The main issue is that you are trying to *Add* colors (from *Reflections*) in parts of your *ViewLayer* that are transparent. No matter what, these regions are still transparent. Reflections pass shouldn't be used with *Add* blend mode, but rather with *Alpha Over* or *Mix*. I'm not sure how to go about it, though.

Comment: I still don't understand why the reflection would show in the render view but not in the saved file, it's so confusing!

Comment: Because Blender render view let's you see colors also in transparent region. Unintuitive at first but standard behavior. In render view, you can change *Display Channels* (top-right corner) to *Alpha* to check your alpha channel.